# Have I missed something? "Aluminum is even simpler than Silicon: one atom per unit cell in a fcc lattic"?

Tags: quantum-espresso, crystallography

In [this tutorial](https://www.materialscloud.org/learn/data/learn/files/Zem3D6woIu3r/1-4a_day1_handson_Giannozzi_.pdf) page 17, it says: "Aluminum is even simpler than Silicon: one atom per unit cell in a fcc lattic".

If it is FCC, then it should be the same as Silicon, two atoms per unit cell, `ibrav=2`.

Comment: Silicon is diamond cubic. Space group Fd3m (227) while aluminium is Fm3m (225). For primitive unit cell, we need one atom for aluminium while you need atleast two in Silicon.

Comment: @Pranavkumar Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Pranavkumar can you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silicon is diamond cubic in its most stable phase, with a space group of $Fd\bar{3}m$ (227), whereas aluminum is face-centered cubic with a crystal symmetry of $Fm\bar{3}m$ (225). The conventional unit cell of aluminum has four atoms, whereas silicon has eight atoms. However, the diamond cubic structure can be seen as the interlocking of two FCC systems translated by $(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)$ of the lattice parameter, as shown in the figure below:
[image]

The primitive unit cell of silicon is same as aluminium with additional motif at $(0.25,0.25,0.25)$.

Sample example of Silicon primitive and conventional unit cell

```
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Si           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Si           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 

CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      2.7154800000       2.7154800000       0.0000000000
      2.7154800000       0.0000000000       2.7154800000
      0.0000000000       2.7154800000       2.7154800000
```

```
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Si           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Si           0.2500000000       0.7500000000       0.7500000000 
Si           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Si           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 
Si           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Si           0.7500000000       0.7500000000       0.2500000000 
Si           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
Si           0.7500000000       0.2500000000       0.7500000000 
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      5.4309600000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       5.4309600000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000       5.4309600000
```

Sample example of Aluminium primitive and conventional unit cell

```
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Al           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 

CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      2.0200000000       2.0200000000       0.0000000000
      2.0200000000       0.0000000000       2.0200000000
      0.0000000000       2.0200000000       2.0200000000
```

```
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Al           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Al           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Al           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Al           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      4.0400000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       4.0400000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000       4.0400000000
```

Comment: for a nice image; [Primitive unit cell of fcc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210963/83380)